# Angularjs render iframe from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soundcloud

I'm working on an angular app and am having some trouble rendering a soundcloud emebed iframe in my html. As you can see from my code below, i'm printing out all the tracks in the array that gets built in my getTracks function. All of the data gets called and stored properly in $scope, and I can see that in my console debug in the controller. When I add the embedIframe property to the object, without trustAsHtml it renders out as text, if I use ng-bind-html it renders in the html tag it'self, not inside of it. When I pass it through trustAsHtml i just get nothing back in the html. the embedIframe prop gets a function called 
'TrustedValueHolderType' but it doesn't seem to store anything.. or I don't know how to get the data from that.

Any tips anybody could give me would be great! And if you need anymore info just ask.

My HTML

```
<section id="grid" ng-controller="GridCtrl">
            <div class="track flipped" ng-repeat="track in soundcloud.tracks">
                <div class="front">
                    <img src="images/loading.gif" />
                </div>
                <div class="back" ng-bind-html="{{track.embedIframe}}"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

My Controller

```
.controller("GridCtrl", ['$scope', 'Soundcloud', function($scope, Soundcloud){

        // Init the Soundcloud SDK config
        Soundcloud.initialize();

        // Store tracks in the $scope
        $scope.soundcloud = Soundcloud.getTracks();

        //Debug
        console.log( "GridCtrl", $scope.soundcloud);

    }])
```

My Service

```
getTracks: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = deferred.promise;
                promise.tracks = [];

            SC.get("/me/tracks", function(response){

                // Push Tracks
                promise.tracks = response;
                resolve(null, response, deferred);

            }); //SC.get

            promise.then(function(tracks){
                $.each(tracks, function(k, v){
                    if(v.sharing == 'public'){
                        SC.oEmbed(v.uri, function(oembed){
                            promise.tracks[k].embedIframe = $sce.trustAsHtml( oembed.html );
                            resolve(null, oembed, deferred);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            return promise;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Angular isn't great, but it kind of looks like:

```
<div class="track flipped" ng-repeat="track in soundcloud.tracks">
```

should be:

```
<div class="track flipped" ng-repeat="track in soundcloud">
```

i.e. soundcloud is the list, as opposed to having the list.

Answer (score 0):

iFrames source needs angular $sce.RESOURCE_URL

Answer (score 0):

Sure you've figured this out by now, but just solved this myself. You need use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service to tell angular to render 'trusted' html content into your view.

You can do this by creating a filter:

```
// Trust as embed
.filter('trustEmbed', function ($sce) {
    return function (value) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
    };
})
```

Then pass this filter along with your embed code:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="embed_code | trustEmbed"></div>
</div>
```